# Why the namespace have not exists?

Tags: c#, namespaces

When i am program with C#,it give tips:

namespace `Framework`have not exists class or namespace `DALFactory`.

But it really exists,and i added the reference `framework`.

and `using Framework.DALFactory;`

When i input a '.' after `framwork` it has a choose of DALFactory!!!

How could this happen? And some class has the same error.

Thank you.

This is the error message:

```
Error:  25  namespace “Framework” not exists class or namespace “DALFactory”。
Is lack of dll or reference?
```

Solution:

Thank you!When i recompile the `Framework` dll,the problem solved.

Comment: Please post the *exact* error message you receive as well.

Comment: Is the reference 'framework' not some other reference with the same name but doesn't contain DALFactory?

Comment: Does the project that contains `Framework.DALFactory` compile?  If it's in the same solution and it doesn't compile, the reference won't work.

Comment: Do you have the namespace `Framework.DALFactory` in your `framework` DLL?

Comment: I've seen some pretty confusing error messages in my time but that one takes the cake

Comment: What program is generating that message?  It doesn't come from the Microsoft C# compiler.

Comment: @BenVoigt:  The message was translated from Japanese.

Comment: @zimdanen: even if the message text is translated, the error number is not from the Microsoft C# compiler.  So Dolphin still needs to tell us what program generated it.

Comment: @BenVoigt - That's probably the error number from the Error List window in Visual Studio.  The number on the left side.

Comment: @Chris: If he's getting "errors" from the Visual Studio editor and not from compiler output, then he may have Intellisense failures mixed in.  That's why I ask what program he's getting the error from.  "From Visual Studio" is different in several ways from "From csc"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely, you are targetting a framework that does not support the assembly you're trying to use.  Check the target framework for the `framework` assembly and make sure yours is at least as permissive.  (For example, if `framework` is built for `.NET Framework 4.0` and you are targetting `.NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile`, you need to switch to `.NET Framework 4.0`.  If `framework` is built for `.NET Framework 4.5` and you are targetting `.NET Framework 4.0`, you need to switch to `.NET Framework 4.5`.)